Does $\int f_n d\mu_n \rightarrow 0$, if $f_n \rightarrow 0$ p.w. and $\langle \mu_n \rangle$ converges to a finite measure?
Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ be a measure space where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$,compact, $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel sigma algebra, $\mu$ is a finite measure which is absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure.
Let $\left\langle f_n\right\rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of $\mathcal{B}$-measurable functions $f_n: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $|f_n| \leq 1$ for all $n$ and $f_n \rightarrow 0$ pointwise.
Let $\left\langle \mu_n\right\rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of finite measures $\mu_n: \mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $\mu_n \rightarrow \mu$ weakly, i.e.,$\int f \mathrm{~d} \mu_n \rightarrow \int f \mathrm{~d} \mu$ for all continuous functions $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
I have to prove the following:
$$\int f_n d\mu_n \rightarrow 0$$
I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help is most appreciated.

Hint: $|<f_n,μ_n>| \le |<f_n,μ>| + |<f_n, μ_n-μ>|$ where $<f,μ>=\int f dμ$

$|<f_n, \mu_n>| \leq|<f_n, \mu>|+|<f_n, \mu_n-\mu>|$, the first term goes to 0 by the dominated convergence thm. The second term, $|<f_n, \mu_n-\mu>| \leq <|f_n|, |\mu_n-\mu|> \leq  \int d|\mu_n-\mu|,$ bec $|f_n|\leq 1$. After this I'm confused: Does $\mu_n$ converging wkly to $\mu$ imply $\int d|\mu_n-\mu| \rightarrow 0$?

The comment above is of very little use. It takes you 1% towards the solution. I don't know why it is being upvoted.

Geetha ma'am, thank you for your comment. Could you kindly guide me regarding my confusion described above/any other mistake I'm making towards the solution?

I may be missing something, but I think the @gerw answer is correct. See my comments under the answer.

@geetha290krm , I may be missing something, but I think the answer (counter-example) by gerw is correct. See my comments under the answer.

Here is a counterexample. We take $K = [0,1]$. Next, we set
$$
f_n := \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} \chi_{\left[ \frac i n , \frac i n + \frac 1 {n^2}\right]}.
$$
Let $\mu_n$ be the measure with density $n f_n$. Then, $\mu_n$ converges weakly towards the Lebesgue measure and
$$
\int_K f_n \, \mathrm{d}\mu_n = 1
.
$$
Finally, we observe that $f_n$ converges towards $0$ in measure. Consequently, a subsequence of $(f_n)$ converges pointwise a.e. to $0$. Further, this subsequence can be modified on a null set to obtain pointwise convergence everywhere.
Edit: As requested, here is a proof of the weak convergence of $\mu_n$.
Let $f$ be a continuous function and let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary.
Due to uniform continuity, there exists $n$ such that
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \le \varepsilon \qquad\forall x,y \in K, |x - y| \le \frac1n.$$
Consequently,
$$
\left|
n \int_{\frac i n} ^{\frac i n + \frac 1 {n^2}} f \,\mathrm d x
-
\int_{\frac i n}^{\frac {i + 1} n} f \, \mathrm d x
\right|
\le
\frac\varepsilon n.
$$
Summing over $i = 0, \ldots, n-1$ yields
$$
\left|
\int f \, \mathrm d \mu_n
-
\int f \, \mathrm d \lambda
\right|
\le \varepsilon.
$$

The penultimate step looks misterious.

For the penultimate step, you just make a substitution in the first integral such that the integration domain is also $(i/n, (i+1)/n)$. For which values of $i$, $n$ and $\varepsilon$ do you get failure?

Why not? You should get something like $|\int_{i/n}^{(i+1)/n} f( i/n + n (x - i/n)) - f(x) , \mathrm{d}x|$. The integrand can be bounded by $\varepsilon$ due to uniform continuity.

$i/n + n (x - i/n)$ is not close to $x$ when $x$ is near $\frac {i+1} n$.

Then the substitution seems to be wrong. $i/n$ should be mapped to $i/n$ and $(i+1)/n$ should be mapped to $i/n + 1/n^2$.

I may be missing something, but I think the @gerw counter-example is correct.
To prove that $$
\left|
n \int_{\frac i n} ^{\frac i n + \frac 1 {n^2}} f ,\mathrm d x
\int_{\frac i n}^{\frac {i + 1} n} f , \mathrm d x
\right|
\le
\frac\varepsilon n.
$$
we can do a change of variable in the first integral. Define $y= \frac{i}{n} +n (x - \frac{i}{n})$. So $\mathrm d y = n \mathrm d x$ and $x= \frac{i}{n} +\frac{1}{n}(y - \frac{i}{n})$. So (continue)

$$n \int_{\frac i n} ^{\frac i n + \frac 1 {n^2}} f(x) ,\mathrm d x = \int_{\frac i n}^{\frac {i+1} n} f\left (\frac{i}{n} +\frac{1}{n}(y - \frac{i}{n}) \right), \mathrm d y= \int_{\frac i n}^{\frac {i+1} n} f\left (\frac{i}{n} +\frac{1}{n}(x - \frac{i}{n}) \right), \mathrm d x$$ Note that, for all $x \in [\frac{i}{n}, \frac {i + 1} n]$, we have $\frac{i}{n} +\frac{1}{n}(x - \frac{i}{n}) \in [\frac{i}{n}, \frac i n + \frac 1 {n^2}]$, and so $$\left | \left  (\frac{i}{n} +\frac{1}{n}(x - \frac{i}{n}) \right)-x  \right | \leq \frac 1 n$$ So, by the absolute continuity, we have (continue)

$$\left| n \int_{\frac i n} ^{\frac i n+\frac 1 {n^2}} f ,\mathrm d x- \int_{\frac i n}^{\frac{i+1} n} f , \mathrm d x
\right|= \left |  \int_{\frac i n}^{\frac{i+1} n} f\left (\frac{i}{n} +\frac{1}{n}(x - \frac{i}{n}) \right) , \mathrm d x - \int_{\frac i n}^{\frac{i+1} n} f , \mathrm d x\right | \le \frac\varepsilon n.$$
